# Magento 2: Cron configuration error?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cron, magento-cron

Every time the cron runs it logs this error:

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
 Invalid Document
 Element 'group': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( job ).
 Line: 24



cron:run [--group="..."] [--bootstrap="..."]
```

the crontab -e shows this at line 24:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.0 /var/www/html/store/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/store/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

I checked official documentation and didn't found any significal differences between these lines aside from paths. 
Does anyone knows what "group" is missing and how do i fix that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the answer, Anton, but i found out that the problem was caused by an extension Cedcommerce Walmart - their crontab.xml file had "job" section conmmented inside "group" section.

Uncommenting it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

This is Magento core bug that should be fixed in 2.2.4 version.

You can find `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd` for a manual update and change #12 line

from `<xs:element name="event" type="eventDeclaration" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">`

to  `<xs:element name="event" type="eventDeclaration" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">`